# How do i single qoute in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am working with jsp . i need to know how to escape values , so it will good for mysql database. I thought i could just use reg expressing to find the occurrence and then replace them but that doest seem to be a very good approach. Please can someone help me out here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You just need a good [reference](http://bobby-tables.com/java) on how to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

It depends on what database access layer you're using. Placeholders are the best way to do this.

**DO NOT** write your own regular expression to do this. You will get it wrong. Escaping is harder than you might think. The basics is to escape quotes, but there are other, more subtle details to do with international characters and binary data that need to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes should not give any issue in HTML/JSP.

Regarding the database, you should use prepared statements to avoid issues with single quotes or line breaks. Prepared statements are also much safer, protecting from SQL injections.

An example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/jdbc_prepared_statement.htm).